Radon Nikodym derivative and distribution function
Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta$ the  Borel-Lebesgue measure over $\mathfrak{B}$. Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure over $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. the distribution function
$$\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \hspace{10px} \varphi(x) =\begin{cases}
    -\mu((x,0]), &x<0,\\
    0, &x=0,\\
    \mu((0,x]), &x>0
\end{cases}$$
is differentiable and $\varphi'$ is continuous. I want to prove that $\varphi'(x) = \frac{d \mu}{d \beta}(x)$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.
Here is my attempt: If $\varphi'$ is continuous then it is integrable so
$$
F(x) = \int^x_a \varphi(y) dy
$$
is differentiable almost everywhere and $F'(x) = \varphi$. Is this a step in the right direction?

It is not. It might be more promising to apply the FTC to $\varphi$ instead of $F,.$

Since $\mu$ is a Borel Measure, and $\varphi$ is an increasing function, let $\beta_{\varphi}$ denote the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure correspoding to $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}$. That is, a function $\beta_{\varphi}$ such that
$$ \beta_{\varphi}((a,b]) = \varphi(b) - \varphi(a), \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}.$$
In particular, since $\varphi'(x)$ exists, and is continuous, it is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$ and by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have that
this function is unique and satisfies
$$ \beta_{\varphi}((a,b]) = \int_a^b \varphi'(t) dt.$$
We will prove that $\beta_{\varphi} \ll \beta$.
The restriction of $\varphi$ to each closed interval $[a,b]$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous because its derivative is continuous, thus, the
restriction of $\varphi'$ to a closed interval $[a,b]$ is bounded. Let $A$ be a $\beta-$null set in $\mathfrak{B}$, and consider $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon>0$.
Then, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $I_k = (a_k,b_k)$, $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ are pairwise disjoint open intervals of $[-m, m]$ satisfying
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n |b_k - a_k| < \delta,$$
then
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(b_k) - \varphi(a_k) < \varepsilon.$$
Since $\mu$ is a Borel measure, $\beta_{\varphi}$ is regular, and this implies there is an
open set $U$ such that $A \bigcap (-m, m) \subseteq U$ and $\beta(U) < \delta$. Let $U := U \bigcap (-m, m) \subseteq (-m,m)$, then $U$ is an open set in $\mathfrak{B}$ and
$U$ is the union of a countable number of pairwise disjoint open intervals $I_k = (a_k,b_k)$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, we have that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k - a_k) \leq \beta(U) < \delta.$$
Therefore, we have that
\begin{align*}
    \beta_{\varphi}(U) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_{\varphi}(I_k)\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \varphi(b_k) - \varphi(a_k)\\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(b_k) - \varphi(a_k)\\
    &< \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Since the choice of $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have that
$\beta_{\varphi}(A \bigcap (-m,m)) = 0$ and since $m$ was arbitrary, we have that
\begin{align*}
    \beta_{\varphi}(A) &= \beta_{\varphi}(\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty A \cap (-m,m))\\
    &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \beta_{\varphi}(A \cap (-m,m))\\
    &= 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\beta_{\varphi} \ll \beta$.
Finally, by the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, there is a $\beta-$measurable function $h$ on
$\mathbb{R}$ such that $\beta_\varphi = h \beta$. Now, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
then $\chi_{[-n,n]} \beta_{\varphi} = \chi_{[-n,n]} h \beta$ is a finite measure and thus
$\chi_{[-n,n]} h$ is Lebesgue integrable.
Let $g$ denote the indefinite integral of $\chi_{[-n,n]} h$. Then, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have that
$g' =h$, $\beta-$a.e. on $[-n,n]$ and
\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \int_{(-\infty, t]} \chi_{[-n,n]} h d\beta\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{[-n,x]} d\beta_{\varphi}\\
&= \varphi(x) - \varphi(-n)
\end{align*}
for all $x \in [-n,n]$. Hence, $g' = \varphi'$, $\beta-$a.e. on $[-n,n]$. Since
$n$ was arbitrary, we have that $\varphi' = h$, $\beta-$a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$, and
therefore $\varphi' = \cfrac{d\mu}{d\beta}$, $\beta-$a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$. $\square$
